# Replaying an Audio element in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio

```
sounds["foo"]= new Audio("foo.ogg");
function playSound(id){

var snd = this.sounds[id];

if(snd.currentTime>snd.duration*0.99999){
    snd.pause();
    snd.currentTime=0;
    //snd.seekable.start(); //doesnt work
    //snd.load(); does the trick but with the cost re-downloading the clip every single time
    snd.play();
}
if(snd.currentTime==0)
snd.play();
}
```

For some reason playSound('foo'); works on the first time, but fails after that on Chrome (works just fine on Firefox). Adding snd.load() seemed to fix this, but now it downloads the clip from the server every time the clip is played, which is a lot in my use case.

EDIT: Oh, and snd.currentTime seems to get stuck at the end, so snd.currentTime=0 does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The following script works just fine for me on OSX, Chrome Version 32.0.1700.102 and Firefox 27.0.

If you do not want to loop the file immediately, your script definitely is the right approach.

I couldn't reproduce your issues. I associated the method with an onclick action on a link and used a 5s .ogg file for testing. Clicking the link and re-playing the audio file worked for me all the time.
The only possible issue I noticed is your second if clause. If the first if is matched, the time is set to 0 and the file will be played. Even if it is very unlikely in my opinion, it could be that the second if is also matched and snd.play() is invoked a second time. I therefore would use else if.

Can you give it a try? Even though I suppose it does not solve your problem :/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sounds = [];
    sounds["foo"]= new Audio("foo.ogg");

    /* First solution, creating a loop */
    function playSoundLoop(id){
        var snd = this.sounds[id];  
        snd.play();
        snd.addEventListener('ended', function(){
            this.currentTime = 0;
            this.play();
            }, false);
    }

    /* Use else if instead of if */
    function playSound(id){
        var snd = this.sounds[id];

        if(snd.currentTime>snd.duration*0.99999){
            snd.pause();
            snd.currentTime=0;
            snd.play();
        } else if(snd.currentTime==0) {
            snd.play();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to loop the sound, but to be able to play the sound  again without having to reload it from the server.

Comment: @user1185421
Sorry for that. I updated the answer and mentioned a few other things.